# Java Stack error after getting last element via pop method

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, collections, stack

I have the following code for the solution of [Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/balanced-brackets/problem).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isBalanced("{(([])[])[]}"));
}

public static String isBalanced(String s) {
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
    stack.push(s.charAt(0));

    for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
        Character c = s.charAt(i);
        Character cStack = stack.peek();


        if (cStack == '{' && c == '}' 
            || cStack == '[' && c == ']' 
            || cStack == '(' && c == ')') {
            stack.pop();
        } else {
            stack.push(c);
        }
    }

    if (stack.isEmpty())
        return "YES";
    return "NO";
}
```

Although the code seems to working without any problem, it throws the following error on the Hackerrank page. I already test the input in my local IDE as it is `{(([])[])[]}`, but I am not sure if I need to get the last element (it maybe due to getting it via `Character cStack = stack.peek();` and then `stack.pop();`.

So, could you please have a look at and test this code on [Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/balanced-brackets/problem) page and let me know what is wrong?

***Update:***

```
public static String isBalanced(String s) {
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
    stack.push(s.charAt(0));

    for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
        Character c = s.charAt(i);

        if (c == '{' || c == '[' || c == '(') {
            stack.push(c);
        } else if (stack != null) {
            Character cStack = stack.peek();
            if (cStack == '{' && c == '}'
                    || cStack == '[' && c == ']'
                    || cStack == '(' && c == ')') {
                stack.pop();
            }
        }
    }
    if (stack.isEmpty())
        return "YES";
    return "NO";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before calling `stack.peek()`, you need to check if the stack is empty or not. Calling `pop()` or `peek()` on an empty stack will raise an error.
If the current character is an opening bracket, you don't even need to check the stack top. If it is a closing bracket, then check if the stack is empty or not first. If it is, return false. Otherwise compare the top character and make a decision.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helps. I tried, but still the same error. Could you post the updated code after testing on Hackerrank?

Comment: @Downed_Voters Any comment if you have any idea to post a comment?

Comment: @Jack add your edited approach to the question

Comment: Added as update

Comment: @Jack in the else if block, first check if the stack is empty, then do `Character cStack = stack.peek()`, and then check the remaining statements

Comment: I changed, but gives wrong output. See updated code pls.

Comment: @Jack add an `else` block to the `if (cStack == '{' && c == '}'` condition, where you straightaway return `"NO"`

Comment: Do you mean the last line? If so, I am afraid it would not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243764/discussion-between-abhinav-mathur-and-jack).

Comment: Ok, I fixed my friend by adding an extra `else` block. Thanks a lot.